# A box contains 6 red balls, 4 white balls, and 5 blue balls. Three balls are randomly drawn from the box...?

Tags: probability

A box contains 6 red balls, 4 white balls, and 5 blue balls. Three
balls are randomly drawn from the box (and not replaced). What is the
probability that the order of balls was red, then white, then blue? What is
the probability that the balls came out red, white, blue (in any order)?

A further instruction given was to use the counting method, not the permutations method.

I found to begin that there are 2730 points in all (15x14x13) but am struggling to understand how to find out the odds of the specific order, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is surely a duplicate, but it's probably easier to repeat the answer than to track down the duplicate.

*What is the probability that the order of balls was red, then white, then blue?*

Answer:  $(6/15)*(4/14)*(5/13)$

*What is the probability that the balls came out red, white, blue (in any order)?*

Answer:  $(6/15)*(4/14)*(5/13)*(_3P_3)$

Comment: Why is it 3P3 instead of 3C3?

Comment: I am just curious about the last bit of multiplication for the in any order portion of the question, do you mind explaining the significance of *(3P3)